# How to make expect command in Expect module of perl search for multiple occurences of same string

Tags: perl, perl-module, expect

I have a scenario where i am using expect module of perl to automate terminal based applications. I am passing a regular expression as an argument to the expect command as shown below

```
$ssh->expect(20, '-re',
    'Dev:(\d+)\W*Bdaddr:((?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2})\W*Name:' );
```

So i want to make the same regular expression search for multiple occurrences of the pattern within the string buffer that expect uses. How can it be achieved.Also, I want to know how to capture those multiple occurrences.

Comment: Please edit question to include sample strings that should be matched.

Comment: say i am looking for "Hello". There may be more than one occurrence of Hello in expect buffer.Normally expect returns whenever it first finds "Hello". Now what i want is to get the second occurrence of "Hello" to be find

Answer (score 3):

Check whether this helps.

```
use Expect;

my $Obj = Expect->new();

$Obj->spawn("/some/tst.bash");

$Obj->expect(undef,
    [ qr/(?:.*?Hello){2}/i, sub {
            my $Self = shift;
            print "Matched qr/.*?Hello.*?Hello/i..\n";
            exp_continue; }
    ]
);
```

And **/some/tst.bash** looks like this.

```
echo "Hello! This is for testing. !Hello"
```

Basically the regex **(?:.*?Hello){2}** looks for anything/nothing followed by Hello twice. So in essence the following too would have matched **HelloHello**